# Why does comparison of objects return false in my snake game

Tags: java

```
public class Snake {

    private int snakeLength;
    private Position[] snakeBody;

    public Snake(int row, int col) {
        snakeLength = 1;
        snakeBody = new Position[5];
        Position initial = new Position(row, col);
        snakeBody[0] = initial;
    }

    public boolean snakePosition(Position pos) {
        boolean test = false;
        for(int i = 0; i <= snakeBody.length-1;i++) {
            if (snakeBody[0] != null) {
                boolean isEqual = pos.equals(snakeBody[0]);
                if (isEqual == true) {
                    test = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return test;
    }
```

main method:

```
public class TestAsmt1 {

public static void main(String[] args) {


testPassed = true;
theSnake = new Snake(1,1);
if (!theSnake.snakePosition(new Position(1,1))) testPassed = false;
```

Position:

```
public class Position {

    private int positionRow;
    private int positionColumn;

    public Position(int row, int column) {
        positionColumn = column;
        positionRow = row;
    }

    public boolean equals (Position otherPosition) {
        if(otherPosition.getRow() == this.getRow() && otherPosition.getCol() == this.getCol() ) {
            return true;
        } else {
        return false;
        }
    }


}
```

I don't get why when I compare the objects it returns false. testpassed is supposed to me true. What am I doing wrong? I have been trying to figure this out for at least 2 hours now. Look at the if(pos.equals(snakeBody[i])) line in particular. I saw someone else had this issue too yesterday (this assignment is due tonight at midnight) but they couldn't get it solved. Any idea what the issue is?

Comment: Method signature of `Object.equals(Object)` does not take `Position` argument. You should use the `@Override` annotation **and** your debugger (although this one can be a tricky issue to spot).

Comment: I've never used @override, where would I put it/

Answer (score 2):

What you **are** doing is creating a function called equals that takes a Position object as a parameter. What you **should** be doing is instead overriding the existing equals function that takes an Object as a parameter and implementing the hashCode function as well, completing the **[equals/hashCode](https://www.baeldung.com/java-equals-hashcode-contracts)** contract.

To do this, the Position class needs to contain final fields. You also need to override the functions I stated. This can be done the following way;

```java
    public class Position {

        private final int positionRow;

        private final int positionColumn;

        public Position(int row, int column) {
            positionColumn = column;
            positionRow = row;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals (Object other) {
            if (other == this) {
                return true;
            }
            if (other instanceof Position) {
                Position otherPosition = (Position) other;

                return this.positionRow == otherPosition.positionRow && this.positionColumn == otherPosition.positionColumn;
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(positionRow, positionColumn);
        }

    }
```

It is also worth noting that the function Snake#snakePosition is broken as well. You loop through all indices of the snakeBody array but you only check if the Position parameter is equal to the first object in the snakeBody array at index 0. This is how it can be improved.

```java
        public boolean intersects(Position pos) {
            return Arrays.stream(snakeBody).filter(Objects::nonNull).anyMatch(body -> body.equals(pos));
        }
```

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Snake theSnake = new Snake(1,1);

        boolean testPassed = theSnake.intersects(new Position(1,1));

        System.out.println("Test passed: " + testPassed);
    }
```

Comment: Why do they need to implement the `hashCode` function as well?

Comment: There are some great articles on why you need the hashCode function to complete the equals/hashcode contract. I'll provide them in the main post.